# Best way of representing logical statements

Tags: graphics, best-practices, logic

I have a number of statemts which describe the process of creating a data element which are intergrated within a "data manual". For example:

```
IF ( ( heigth between 58 AND 76 ) AND ( BMI between 19 AND 24 ) ) THEN obese = 0
ELSE IF ( ( heigth between 58 AND 76 ) AND ( BMI between 25 AND 29 ) ) THEN obese = 1
```

Is there an elegant way to represent such statements in TeX? I've thought about using tree graphs of some sort but unortunately its hard due to the fact that most elements are not as simple as the example and tend to get very complicated very fast.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. Do you want to represent the expression as a formula or graphically?

Comment: Either, I dont mind. I was hoping there is already a "canonical" way of expressing such expressions in an elegant manner. I have no preference as long as the result is readable and parseable by members by humans.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure about this, but...

```
$
  \hbox{obese} = \cases{
    0 & if $(58 < \hbox{height} < 76) \land (19 < \hbox{BMI} < 24))$\cr
    1 & if $(58 < \hbox{height} < 76) \land (25 < \hbox{BMI} < 29))$
  }
$
\bye
```

[image]